# Need to extract embedded .docx .xlsx .docm files from the .doc file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am currently trying to extract embedded objects from MS Word doc in HWPFDocument and PFB the code which extracts other file types

``

```
document = new HWPFDocument(fs);
     DirectoryNode docRootDir = fs.getRoot();
     DirectoryNode objPoolDir;
     // Read ROOT POIFS
     Iterator<Entry> docRootDirIter = docRootDir.getEntries();
     String fileName = null;
     int fileNameIndex = 0;
     while(docRootDirIter.hasNext()){
         Entry docRootDirEntry = docRootDirIter.next();

         if (docRootDirEntry.getName().contains("ObjectPool")){
             objPoolDir = (DirectoryNode) docRootDirEntry;

             //Read ObjectPool POIFS directory ---> ObjectPool is location of embedded files within a DOC file
            Iterator<Entry> objPoolDirIter = objPoolDir.getEntries();
            while(objPoolDirIter.hasNext()){
                Entry objPoolDirEntry = objPoolDirIter.next();

               // Read ObjectPool POIFS subdirectories
               if(objPoolDirEntry.isDirectoryEntry()){
                   DirectoryNode objPoolSubDir = (DirectoryNode) objPoolDirEntry;
                   Iterator<Entry> objPoolSubDirIter = objPoolSubDir.getEntries();
                   while (objPoolSubDirIter.hasNext()){
                       Entry objPoolSubDirEntry = objPoolSubDirIter.next();

               // Read embedded OLE10 files, create an OLE object, and write to the OS File system
                       if (objPoolSubDirEntry.isDocumentEntry()){
                           DocumentEntry objPoolSubDirFile = (DocumentEntry) objPoolSubDirEntry;

                           if(objPoolSubDirFile.getName().contains("Ole10Native")){

                           Ole10Native oleEntry = Ole10Native.createFromEmbeddedOleObject(objPoolSubDir);
                           fileName = oleEntry.getLabel();
                           if (fileName == null) 
                                fileName = "unknownOle10Native" + fileNameIndex++ + ".nul";
                           byte[] data =oleEntry.getDataBuffer();
                           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./" + fileName);
                           out.write(data);
                           out.close();
                           if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                              File f = new File(fileName);
                              embeddedFilePaths.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                           }
                     }
                }
           }
           }else if(objPoolDirEntry.isDocumentEntry()){
                DocumentEntry documentEntry = (DocumentEntry) objPoolDirEntry;

                DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = documentEntry.getParent();

                directoryEntry.getEntryNames();

           }
        }
        }else if(docRootDirEntry.getName().contains("WordDocument")){
              DocumentEntry documentEntry = (DocumentEntry) docRootDirEntry;
              System.out.println(documentEntry.getName());
        }
```

``

With this code I am currently able to extract .exe, .zip , .tar, .so , .xml files from the word .doc file using HWPFDocument format, Is it possible to extract .docx , .docm, .xlsx by modifying this code. Here My main problem is to identify between Ole10Native files and MS Files like docx, pptx, xlsx and docm , If i am able to distinguish between them I can be able to proceed with the extraction but even after that How to extract embedded MS files remains problem for me, I am not finding a clear way to extract embedded MS files . Should that logic be in this code block

`if(docRootDirEntry.getName().contains("WordDocument"))`

because the only information about a word doc or xlsx im getting is the doc entry name which is MS Word Document, Also please let me know which condition to use to extract  for PDF as well

Comment: Did you try with Apache Tika? Try with the Tika App in `-z` mode and see if that can do the extraction you want

Comment: I will try it with Apache Tika and update here

Comment: Is it possible to use apache poi for achieving this, currently my entire implementation is in apache poi and it will be a complete rewrite for me to move to apache tika from apache poi

Comment: Apache Tika uses Apache POI internally. If you can get everything you need from Tika, you can see the Tika source for how to do that with POI. If Tika can't get it, likely POI can't easily either

Comment: I am unable to find the correct code where tika reads and extracts from .doc all embedded files, can u please help out by giving an example

Answer (score 0):

In a `POIFSFileSystem` embedded other file systems are in a `DirectoryEntry` having a name containing "ObjectPool".  That you have found already.

But Microsoft Office files in Office Open XML format (`*.xlsx`, `*.docx`, `*.pptx`, ...) internally are ZIP archives and not Ole10Native. They are stored in a `DocumentEntry` named Package. Also there is not any relyable information about file name and content-type. Only the `DocumentEntry` named "\1CompObj" contains some information about the content-type.

Using your code embedded Office Open XML format files should get got via:

```
...
if (objPoolSubDirFile.getName().contains("Ole10Native")) {   
...
} else if (objPoolSubDirFile.getName().contains("Package")) {  
 String extension = ".nul";
 if (objPoolSubDir.hasEntry("\1CompObj")) {
  org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentInputStream documentInputStream = objPoolSubDir.createDocumentInputStream("\1CompObj");
  String text = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(documentInputStream, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
   .lines()
   .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining());
  System.out.println("Package CompObj: " + text);
  if (text.matches(".*Excel.*Macro.*")) extension = ".xlsm";
  else if (text.matches(".*Excel.*")) extension = ".xlsx";
  else if (text.matches(".*Word.*Macro.*")) extension = ".docm";
  else if (text.matches(".*Word.*")) extension = ".docx";
  else if (text.matches(".*PowerPoint.*")) extension = ".pptx";
 }
 org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentInputStream documentInputStream = objPoolSubDir.createDocumentInputStream(objPoolSubDirFile.getName());
 String fileName = "unknownPackage" + fileNameIndex++ + extension;
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./" + fileName);
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int len;
 while ((len = documentInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  out.write(buffer, 0, len);
 }
 out.close();
}
...
```

Btw.: Your questions imply that someone misuses Microsoft Office files as container for other files. That is not what Microsoft Office files are made for. One should stop doing that.

Especially embedding Office Open XML format Microsoft Office files into the old binary Microsoft Office files seems very strange.

Comment: I have to parse some old documents coming in email and filter out any malicious files coming attached in those documents sent by any man in the middle.so i need to write a parser for the same. Thanks a lot for your help Axel.